# 'use' in an OPENQUERY statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to execute a 'use' statement inside an OPENQUERY?

This works:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(
    server_name, 
    'select * from AdventureWorks.Person.Address'
)
```

This doesn't:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(
    server_name, 
    'use AdventureWorks; select * from Person.Address'
)
```

Comment: I think - no. Why you need specify the database directly?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting devart!

Comment: I've got a query that I'd like to execute on production and UAT (two different schemas, same query)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE 
      @SQL NVARCHAR(500)
    , @ServerName NVARCHAR(100) = 'server_name'
    , @DbName NVARCHAR(100) = DB_NAME() -- current db_name

SELECT @SQL = '
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY(
    '+ @ServerName + ', 
    ''SELECT * FROM [' + @DbName + '].Person.Address''
)'

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Thank dev, not bad! Unforunately I don't have much control over the query I'm executing. All I know is the schema it works under.